# php rounding down

Tags: php, rounding, floor

I am trying to round down numbers using PHP.

I have managed to do this if the value has a decimal place, using this method below.

```
$val = floor($val * 2) / 2;
echo 'hello'. $val;
```

If the value I am trying to round down doesn't have a decimal place and the above code is not working.

The values I am trying to round down.

```
32456 => 32000

4567 => 4000

38999 => 38000
```

Comment: If the number doesn't have a fraction, `$val * 2` will be an integer as well, so `floor()` won't change it.

Comment: refer to [round thousand hundrard etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43932648/6521116)

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do this. The most common way (for rounding down to the nearest 1000) would be something like this:

```
function roundDown1000($n)
{
    return floor($n / 1000) * 1000;
}
```

More generally:

```
function roundDown($n, $increment)
{
    return floor($n / $increment) * $increment;
}
```

If you wanted, you could also do `$n - ($n % 1000)`, but this will get weird results for `$n < 0`.