# Round to max thousand, hundred etc in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, rounding

I have a pretty simple PHP question but I'm not sure how to do that.

I want to round to the max hundred or thousand depending on the value returned by the database.

Here are a few examples of what I need :

- DB returns the value 11, I want PHP to output 20
- DB returns the value 104, I want PHP to output 200
- DB returns the value 1404, I want PHP to output 2000
- DB returns the value 10241, I want PHP to output 11000

etc etc

I would like to create an automatic function to do that, according to the value passed.

Thanks!

Comment: please take a look at the accepted answer, maybe it is a solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150001/how-to-round-to-nearest-thousand

Comment: DB returns the value 10241, I want PHP to output 11000 should not that be 20000?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1619265/6521116

Comment: Check my final implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Final implementation**, inspired from [Shaunkak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43933181/6521116) and SO's comment. Thanks for these bra..s. [live demo](https://eval.in/792930)

```
<?php
  $val = 10241.67;
  if($val >= 1000) {
    echo ceil($val / 1000) * 1000;
  }
  else {
    $length = strlen(ceil($val));
    $times = str_pad('1', $length, "0");
    echo ceil($val / $times) * $times;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? ceil(11 / 1000.0) * 1000 => 1000, not 20.

Comment: I means if you want 10 folder, divide 10.0 then multiply 10.

Comment: @LeszekRepie you can check it now

Comment: Nice, it works, thanks! However, I improved it by replacing `strlen($val);` by `strlen(ceil($val));` so it also works with decimal numbers.

Comment: @fraxool, you also can combine with Shaunak Shukla's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43933181/6521116   str_pad.

Comment: This doesn't work with: 10241; OP wants to round to the max hundred or thousand.

Comment: Upvoted to give me the idea for next level answer. But our answer doesn't match with 10242 => 11000! It shows 20000!!!

Comment: Oh, I missed it, is your biggest up offset is 1000.

Answer (score 5):

Really not impressed by everyone using string operations!
Use base 10 logarithm to get the number of zeros in the input.
log<sub>10</sub>x = y is equivalent to 10<sup>y</sup> = x

```php
$zeros = floor(log10($input));
$zeros = min($zeros, 3); // Only round to tens, hundreds or thousands
$tens = pow(10, $zeros);
$result = ceil($input / $tens) * $tens;
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/IvfOu20JRccc8Cuc

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$value = 14;
$len = strlen($value);
$div = str_pad('1', $len, "0");
echo ceil($value / $div) * $div;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I got the idea to put it on your previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<?php
    $input = 10241; //this will be your input
    $charLength = strlen($input);
    $number = [1,10,100,1000,10000,100000];
    $output = ceil($input / $number[$charLength - 1]) * $number[$charLength - 1]; //same like this ceil($input / 10) * 10;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents:

```
$v = 11;

if(strlen($v)<4) { 
    $v = str_pad((int)(substr($v, 0, 1)+1), strlen($v), 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
} else {
    $v = substr($v, 0, -4) . str_pad((int)(substr($v, -4, -3)+1), 4, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
}
```