# Round to Highest Factor with Variable Scale?

Tags: php, math, rounding, floor

PHP's `floor()` and `ceil()` is useful for rounding floats to their nearest integers.

But what if we need to find the highest multiple of 10 (hundreds, thousands, etc.) for a given number?  For example:

```
num_to_scale(538.9)           // 500
num_to_scale(543123654.01234) // 5000000
```

Comment: refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43932669/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/812747). You also can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43932648/6521116).

```
  $floor = floor($v);
  return str_pad(substr($floor, 0, 1), strlen($floor), '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function num_to_scale($number) {
  $multiple=1; $test=1;
  for ($i=1; $test>=1; $i++) {
    $factor = $multiple/10;
    $test = $number/$multiple;
    $multiple = $multiple*10;
    $scale = floor($number/$factor)*$factor;
  } return $scale;
}
```

or more simply:

```
function num_to_scale($n) {
  $m=1; $t=1;
  for ($i=1; $t>=1; $i++) {
    $f=$m/10; $t=$n/$m; $m=$m*10; $s=floor($n/$f)*$f;
  } return $s;
}
```

Combined with a helper function to [convert integers to text strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314997/how-to-convert-amount-in-number-to-words), we can easily do something like this:

```
echo 'Over '.num_to_scale(5395206).' units sold.';
// Over five million units sold.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function num_to_scale($number) {
    $num = (int) floor($number);
    $ln = strlen($num) - 1;

    return (int) floor($num / pow(10, $ln)) * pow(10, $ln);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses logarithm :

```
function num_to_scale($var) {
    $nbDigits = (int)log($var,10);
    return (int)($var/10**$nbDigits)*10**$nbDigits;
}
```