# How to Round Number in php?

Tags: php

I want to round the following numbers

Number1 : 1627400 ===>  1628000

Number2 : 758400 ===> 759000

Number3 : 31600 ===> 32000

my code:

```html
echo round(Number,-3);
```

But the conversion does not work properly

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932648/round-to-max-thousand-hundred-etc-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Have you forgotten to put a $ before the var name?

```
echo round($Number,-3);
```